# ionCube loader installation on macOS Big Sur

Tags: php, macos, apache, webserver, ioncube

I downloaded the Loader Wizard from https://www.ioncube.com/loaders.php
There seem to be so many problems in the wizard:
[image: Wizard]

1. The wizard detects that I'm using macOS x86-64, its okay
2. I download the archive and it contains `ioncube_loader_dar_x.x.so` files for all php versions except 7.4 and 8.x
3. I put the loader files to `/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902`
4. In `/usr/local/etc/php/7.4/conf.d/00-ioncube.ini` I have
   `zend_extension = /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/ioncube_loader_mac_7.4.so`
   But I don't have the loader file for php 7.4 in the downloaded archive. And in the archive there are `ioncube_loader_DAR_x.x.so` files not `ioncube_loader_MAC_x.x.so`
   What are the differences between dar and mac?

---

I manually downloaded macOS (64 bits) loader from official website (not from the link in the wizard) and there was 7.4 in the archive so I proceeded with the installation with this file. But now I have another problems with macOS security 
I had issues with certs and followed this tutorial:
https://www.simplified.guide/macos/apache-php-homebrew-codesign

I signed my php7.4 and loader file with this commands:

```
codesign --sign "Yarik Nashivan" --force --keychain ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db /usr/local/opt/php@7.4/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so  
codesign --sign "Yarik Nashivan" --force --keychain ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/ioncube_loader_mac_7.4.so
```

But I still have an errors in apache logs:

```
Failed loading /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/ioncube_loader_mac_7.4.so: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/ioncube_loader_mac_7.4.so, 9): no suitable image found.
Did find: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/ioncube_loader_mac_7.4.so: code signing blocked mmap() of '/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/ioncube_loader_mac_7.4.so'
/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/ioncube_loader_mac_7.4.so: stat() failed with errno=22
```

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask].

Comment: @OlafKock, thank you for the comment, I replaced image with text

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with default macOS apache2. I installed and configured httpd via homebrew and all works fine:

```
brew install httpd
```